# What techniques can I use to reduce loading times?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Since the introduction of the new Lions Arch, it seems to take much longer for me to zone into this map. I'm talking at least 2-3 minutes. I don't recall the loading times being this long.

What techniques can I use to help speed up my loading times?

Comment: Are you on PC? Consider defragging your harddrive if it is also a Disk drive and not an SSD. I think Arqade frowns on performance related questions, but just in case, you might want to include your computer specs.

Comment: Does `gw.exe /image` still work for GW2?

Comment: Are there still regions? Try loading international or whatever.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Indeed, I was considering Super User, but wondered if the loading times would be specific to the game. Otherwise it'd just be 'buy an ssd'.

Comment: @Mazura It's actually '-image' and yes, it does still work, and I've already tried it to ensure my dat file is up to date. Regions went out with GW, now everyone is on the 'megaserver' you don't get a choice.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an SSD. If your HDD isn't spinning and the CPU usage is low (and all the other reasons a SU question would have to rule out; memory, old laptop, specs, hardware conflicts, ect.) then it's the server or your connection.

Comment: My first thought was because of some [festival changes](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/What-s-with-the-Lion-s-Arch-loading-screen). This is a bug or you should do a clean image.

Comment: -image is not as useful as it was in GW1 - GW2's launcher always performs an update check, setting everything to download, and this command line argument makes it so that it *only* performs the update check. GW2.exe -repair retains its functionality and can still be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of **a hardware solution** than a software one, but after performing upgrades similar to the ones I am about to suggest **I saw notable load time improvements on games**, Guild Wars 2 included.

Installing on an **SSD**/**SSHD** (**SSD HDD Hybrid**) is a viable option.

Although **SSD**s at the size you would probably require are quite pricey, a good quality **SSHD** is usually not much more expensive than it's **HDD** counterparts.

If budget is a larger factor for you **HDD** that run at **7200rpm** are on par with a lot of **SSHD**s and are available at a slightly lower price.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by another answer, other than defragmenting the disc and deleting and then doing a repair of the game files, deleting the local cache, local.dat, does provide a performance improvement.

Local.dat is located in %appdata%/Guild Wars 2/. It contains many local configuration settings, such as keybinds, graphics settings, set nicknames on your friends list, and the size and location of UI elements, but it also contains cached lists of assets for frequently visited areas. In areas that have undergone changes, GW2 may use the cached asset list, load the assets, and then load a whole new set when it goes to see what else it needs.

If you delete local.dat, GW2 will rebuild it based on the most recent version.

Answer (score -1):

Delete Local.dat, that works for me

Comment: Why would that help? And where can you find this file?

Comment: Also, "The Local.dat file, located in %appdata%/Guild Wars 2/, contains all local information relating to the Guild Wars client, **including settings, nicknames, and saved login information.**" ([wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Local.dat), emphasis mine) sounds like this is not a file you should tell anyone to delete without warning him about the effects.